# Get value of nth input element using eq()

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var i = input.eq(2).val();
alert(parseInt(i));
```

I'm trying to get the value of the 3rd input, but it returns nothing. I had it saying [Object] [object] at one point. How do I just get the value of the input?

Comment: post your complete code. What is `input`?

Comment: is input a saved jQuery object?  like: var input = $('input') ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Jquery's .eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) api like this

```
  var i = $('input').eq(2).val();
  alert(parseInt(i));
```

or as your code looks that has input as a variable then you need to do this

```
var input = $('input');
var i = input.eq(2).val();
alert(parseInt(i));
```

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/sachinyadav/aTaxs/)

Answer (score 1):

It will be helpful if you provide more information about:

1. What's input? A jQuery object that Sachin mentioned?
2. What's the value of i? Is it what you want after the execution?
3. What will be returned after you call parseInt?

You can also use eq in your input selector:

```
var i = $("input:eq(2)").val();
alert(i);
```

Hope it's helpful.